# How to manage lists with YouTube Iframes API

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, video, youtube

I am having some problem trying to manage a lists of videos in my personal blog.
All the videos are inside an iframe tag (e.g. `<iframe class="YTvideo" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="344" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LeAkYuMDVGY?wmode=opaque" width="459"></iframe>`).
There're 4 videos in this blog, and I'm trying to measure how often those videos are played. I'm trying the following code.

```
//import YT lib
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onYouTubeIframesAPIReady(){
  var frame = document.querySelectorAll('iframe[src*="youtube"]');
  var player = [frame.length];
  for(var i=0; i < frame.length; i++){
    //setting enable js api as true so I can manage the events via JS
    frame[i].src += "&enablejsapi=true";

    //incorporate the each frame to a specific place on the array of players 
    player[i] = new YT.Player(frame[i]);
    player[i].addEventListener('onStateChange', onPlayerStateChange);
  }
}
var onPlayerStateChange = function(event){
  console.log(event.data);
}
```

When executing the code it returns with the following error:

> googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/962985656/?aid=AAA…N5v‌​JSNXPEwA&foc_id=sooa4yRKGN_zEE8iknghZA&label=followon_view&ptype=view:1 GET https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/962985656/…3DN5‌​vJSNXPEwA&foc_id=sooa4yRKGN_zEE8iknghZA&label=followon_view&ptype=view net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: what is the error or problem you are having?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention it. The browser throws the following:
`googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/962985656/?aid=AAA…N5vJSNXPEwA&foc_id=sooa4yRKGN_zEE8iknghZA&label=followon_view&ptype=view:1 GET https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/962985656/…3DN5vJSNXPEwA&foc_id=sooa4yRKGN_zEE8iknghZA&label=followon_view&ptype=view net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

Comment: Hi anon, did you find solution to this?